# Can you create threads outside __ global __?

Tags: c, cuda

Can I create threads in _*device _* like:

```
__device__ float func() 
{
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  // do stuff

  return some_float;
}
```

Or can you only make threads in _*global _* kernels?

Comment: `return float;` is not legal C, C++, or CUDA C/C++.

Answer (score 4):

```
int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
```

Short answer: The above line of code is perfectly valid in `__device__` functions.

However it does not "create" threads.  It simply computes an index in `idx` for the current thread, using that thread's values of `threadIdx.x`, `blockIdx.x` and `blockDim.x`.

The only way to create threads in CUDA is to launch a kernel using the `<<<>>>` syntax to specify the number and grouping of threads using block and grid dimensions:

```
int blockSize = 128;
int gridSize = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

myKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>();
```